# How do I get only names of active plugins in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to to get list of active Wordpress plugins and for that I am using  wp plugin list --status=active --allow-root command.

That gives me putout like this.

```
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+
| name           | status | update | version |
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+
| akismet        | active | none   | 4.2.2   |
| classic-editor | active | none   | 1.6.2   |
| contact-form-7 | active | none   | 5.5.6   |
| wordfence      | active | none   | 7.5.9   |
| wpforms-lite   | active | none   | 1.7.3   |
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Not sure how do I remove extra tables and get only names of the plugin such as

```
akismet
classic-editor
contact-form-7
wordfence
wpforms-lite
```

any help in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result using awk and grep

`wp plugin list --status=active --allow-root > list.txt cat list.txt  | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v -e "name" > plugin.txt`

Comment: Can you show content of `list.txt`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).